# Python vegas error

Tags: python, numerical-integration

I recently installed the vegas Monte Carlo integration package (version 3.0.1) on my Windows 10 machine, which uses Python 2.7. Everything seemed to go OK, and I can import vegas. I copied this code from the vegas tutorial:

```
import vegas
import math

def f(x):
    dx2 = 0
    for d in range(4):
        dx2 += (x[d] - 0.5) ** 2
    return math.exp(-dx2 * 100.) * 1013.2118364296088

integ = vegas.Integrator([[-1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]])

result = integ(f, nitn=10, neval=1000)
print result.summary()
print 'result = %s    Q = %.2f' % (result, result.Q)
```

Running this from a Jupyter notebook, I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c50a62cfad78> in <module>()
     10 integ = vegas.Integrator([[-1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]])
     11 
---> 12 result = integ(f, nitn=10, neval=1000)
     13 print result.summary()
     14 print 'result = %s    Q = %.2f' % (result, result.Q)

src/vegas/_vegas.pyx in random_batch (src/vegas/_vegas.c:19152)()

src/vegas/_vegas.pyx in vegas._vegas.VegasResult.__init__ (src/vegas/_vegas.c:31214)()

src/vegas/_vegas.pyx in vegas._vegas.RAvg.__init__ (src/vegas/_vegas.c:24657)()

src/gvar/_gvarcore.pyx in gvar._gvarcore.GVarFactory.__call__ (src/gvar/_gvarcore.c:15024)()

src/gvar/_svec_smat.pyx in gvar._svec_smat.smat.append_diag (src/gvar/_svec_smat.c:7055)()

src/gvar/_svec_smat.pyx in gvar._svec_smat.smat.append_diag (src/gvar/_svec_smat.c:6723)()

ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'intp_t' but got 'long'
```

I would appreciate any troubleshooting suggestions.
EDIT:
I realize now that the problem is with the Gvar package, which is a prerequisite package for vegas. I can reproduce the same error as follows:

```
import gvar as gv
x = gv.gvar(0, 0.3)
```

As before, I am after troubleshooting suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: It's unlikely, but make sure you have all the dependencies installed. 

`numpy, cython, gvar`  the install would have probably failed if these modules weren't detected. I can't reproduce that error, so that's the only suggestion i have at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the vegas author, who determined that the issue had to do with Windows using 32-bit floats, not 64-bit as Unix-based systems do. He fixed the problem by issuing a revised version of gvar (8.0) that works on Windows properly.